# SSLv2 in IIS 7.5?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, security

Just found that SSLv2 is enabled in IIS 7.5 by default and to change it [requires tweaking in registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187498). What is the design decision for it? Is there a disadvantage of disabling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enabled by default in Server 2008 R2 for backwards compatibility for really ancient client applications.

For most web servers, all client browsers support at least SSLv3; SSLv2 can be safely disabled.